# Endless loading sudo npm from jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, sudo

OS: MacOS

In my jenkins job contain string `npm run build`. It run npm scripts, if I run this command from terminal as sudo all is ok, but in my Jenkins this command is laoding endlessly. No errors, no logs, just endless loading.

In `/etc/sudoers` I added the  string:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But it doesn't help me. Please help me.

Comment: Just wondering: Don't you want to build it for production, i.e. `npm run build --prod` or `ng build --prod` if you are deploying it with Jenkins? That's what I am using in my Jenkins job. You might also want to try the  `--verbose` option of `npm`, that should hopefully give you some logging.

Comment: in my package.json build command contain --prod flag and another flags for prod build. But in this case it does not matter

Comment: I solved my problem running jenkins via sudo, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable problem is that you would have to specify the full path of `npm`, something like `/usr/bin/npm` instead of `npm`.